# Pig programming with conditions

Tags: apache-pig

my input files are below

table1.txt

```
232,100,surender
232,101,raja
```

table2.txt

```
232,100,chennai
232,300,banglore


table1 = load table1.txt using PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray,pwd:chararray,name:chararray);
table2 = load table2.txt using PigStorage(',') as (mid:chararray,mpwd:chararray,city:chararray);
joined = join table1 by (id,pwd) LEFT OUTER, table2 by(mid,mpwd);
result = foreach joined generate id,pwd,name,city,(city == 'chennai' ? 'TN' : 'BN' ) as state;
```

i am expecting ouput as

```
(232,100,surender,chennai,TN)
(232,101,raja,,BN)
```

but i am getting output as below

```
(232,100,surender,chennai,TN)
(232,101,raja,,)
```

Can some one help me on this.. it is replacing only in matching records .. why is it not replacing at unmacthed records from table1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Pig reference manual](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#nulls-ops) for arithmetic operators, including the ternary `?:` operator:

> If either subexpression is null, the resulting expression is null.

The logical operators `AND` and `OR` can short-circuit, so if you instead do

```
(city IS NOT NULL AND city == 'chennai' ? 'TN' : 'BN')
```

or

```
(city IS NULL OR city != 'chennai' ? 'BN' : 'TN')
```

then you should get the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Now this just a guess but try to change order in your comparison to `('chennai' == city ? 'TN' : 'BN')`.

The problem might be with that city is NULL and comparison fails completely.

Comment: The order of the comparison does not matter.

Comment: Good catch! I hadn't noticed this before. I must take this into account in my code.